# In how many ways can two particular players be in the first 5 of the selection list?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The starting 5 in a basketball team is to be picked, in order, from the 10 players in the squad. Determine how many ways can this be done if Jamahl and Anfernee must be in the first 5 players (starting 5)

Textbook's answer: $\mathbb336$

My approach: As it has stated "starting 5", let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be the positions of both of them. However, they have not stated to select the exact position, so there are 2 ways to arrange them in the 2 position.

$P_1$$P_2$

$P_2$$P_1$

The remaining three players can be arranged in $^8P_3$ ways.

The answer:
2 $\cdot$ $^8P_3$ = 336 $\cdot$ 2 = 672

My answer differs as I have included  the additional 2 arrangements of Jamahl and Anfernee, but the question did not stated whether their positions are fixed respectively. I know I am wrong, and it does not mean the textbook is wrong. But, if you could provide me a justification, then it would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not clear.  We can reverse engineer the answer...if we assume that the positions of J and A are pre-set then it works.  Indeed, with that extra assumption there are three open positions, $8$ choices for the first, $7$ for the second, $6$ for the third and $8\times 7\times 6=336$.  But the problem does not tell us that $J,A$ have preset positions.

Comment: Based on the problem statement, I would have concluded that there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 = 6720$ possible selections since there are five ways to place Jamahl and four ways to place Anfernee among the first five positions, then $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ ways to fill the remaining three positions with the remaining eight players.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Hello, yes that's what I had initially wrote, but then I mad assumption that they must be in first two positions.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Indeed, the problem is not clear, and my teacher had given explanation that would match with the textbook's answer. So, I thought why not clarify the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assuption is that: either the book did not consider the positions of Jamahl and Anfernee can be switched and be the same, OR the book assumed that people would not think of the additional 2 arrangements. So the first option is the book is wrong and the latter is the one where you are wrong.

I advise you to seek advice from your teacher and see what they've got to say about that. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely consider  you suggestion.